# Which of these two solutions is more efficient? (Java Hashset)

Tags: java

I have a text file full of words. I want to add each of these words to a hashset. I also have a hashset of words I do not want.

Is it more efficient to:

- (A) Add all the words to the hashset I want and remove the hashset of words I do not want at the end.
- (B) Check if each word is in the hashset of words I do not want and if it is, ignore it. If it is not then add it to the set of words I do want.

*Edit*
There is far more words I want, than words I do not want.

Comment: I vote option B. Why would you want to add words you don't want only to remove them?

Comment: The answers you got are terrible.  In reality the performance of both methods will be similar.  Assuming that there are many more words in your text file than there are in the set of words you don't want, then (A) will be faster, because it requires fewer hash set checks.  It can be up to twice as fast, depending on how many times each word in the text file tends to occur.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Care to give your two cents in an answer?

Comment: Hey Nai, would appreciate an accept if my answer helped. If not, i'd love to know why. Thanks!

Comment: @Nai, putting my answer in an answer isn't going to make you any more certain.  Both of these procedures are easy to write, so you should just test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends completely on the size of your lists. If you have 99999 words you don't want and 1 word you do, you should do option A. If you have 99999 words you want and 1 word you don't, you should do option B.

The reason behind this is obvious - option B gets more and more efficient the smaller the hash set of undesired words is since you have to check that entire set any time you insert a new word using option B.

From a purely theoretical view, both are the same in terms of worst case time complexity, but practically, there can be a big difference.

So basically, as with most solutions, the efficiency depends on how you expect your data to be structured.

Comment: I updated my question to give you more insight to the data I'm working with.

Comment: @Nai I just saw that. So like I said in my answer, since the set of words you don't want is much smaller than the set of words you do, option B is definitely best.

Comment: Checking for an item in a hash set takes pretty much the same time no matter how big it is